How to sort the array which is in date format latest record on top using javascript
I am having an array
let array = [
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "16/03/2023"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "17/03/2022"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "13/04/2024"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "06/03/2024"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "06/02/2024"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "12/03/2024"}
];

I am having the date in the day, month, year format when i try
array.sort((a, b) => {
      const dateA = new Date(a.clmFirstReceivedDt).getTime();
      const dateB = new Date(b.clmFirstReceivedDt).getTime();
      return dateB - dateA;
    });

when the format is month, day, year its working fine but when the date format is changed then order is not getting sorted properly

The Date constructor can't parse just any arbitrary date format correctly, there are limitations. If your format is not one that is broadly supported across different browsers - then you will need to parse it yourself.

To ensure proper sorting regardless of the date format, you should parse the date string manually before creating the Date object. You can achieve this by splitting the date string and creating a new Date object with the year, month, and day in the correct order.


let array = [
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "16/03/2023"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "17/03/2022"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "13/04/2024"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "06/03/2024"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "06/02/2024"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "12/03/2024"}
];

array.sort((a, b) => {
  const getDateFromString = (dateString) => {
    const [day, month, year] = dateString.split('/');
    return new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day}`).getTime();
  };

  const dateA = getDateFromString(a.clmFirstReceivedDt);
  const dateB = getDateFromString(b.clmFirstReceivedDt);
  
  return dateB - dateA;
});

console.log(array);




I would trust yyyy/mm/dd more than yyyy-mm-dd

The hyphen is ISO standard. Still I think the conversion to Date is overkill as you already have the lexical order.

How the Date constructor parses such strings should not be relied on. Instead construct strings you can order lexically, or their numeric equivalent. Here I rearrange the numeric parts to create one big number (yyyymmdd) and then it works:


let array = [
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "16/03/2023"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "17/03/2022"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "13/04/2024"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "06/03/2024"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "06/02/2024"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "12/03/2024"}
];

array.sort((a, b) => {
    // Extract the numeric parts and rejoin them in the propper order
    const dateA = a.clmFirstReceivedDt.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(.*)/, "$3$2$1");
    const dateB = b.clmFirstReceivedDt.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(.*)/, "$3$2$1");
    return dateB - dateA; // for descending order
});

console.log(array);



Avoiding regex, you can slice the string:


let array = [
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "16/03/2023"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "17/03/2022"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "13/04/2024"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "06/03/2024"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "06/02/2024"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "12/03/2024"}
];

array.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.clmFirstReceivedDt.slice(6).localeCompare(a.clmFirstReceivedDt.slice(6)) ||
           b.clmFirstReceivedDt.slice(3).localeCompare(a.clmFirstReceivedDt.slice(3)) ||
           b.clmFirstReceivedDt.localeCompare(a.clmFirstReceivedDt)
});

console.log(array);




Interesting use of (..) instead of (\d{2})  - quite elegant when the format is certain

a good approach to avoid date conversion but slow due regex, check my answer for a benchmark

@AlexanderNenashev, if we are looking at speed (not the question though), then please see the version I added to my answer.

@trincot now on pair with my solution but seems slightly faster with huge arrays, nice one

There you go, if you want to sort the dates which are in the dd/mm/yy format ->
let array = [
    {clmFirstReceivedDt: "16/03/2023"},
    {clmFirstReceivedDt: "17/03/2022"},
    {clmFirstReceivedDt: "13/04/2024"},
    {clmFirstReceivedDt: "06/03/2024"},
    {clmFirstReceivedDt: "06/02/2024"},
    {clmFirstReceivedDt: "12/03/2024"}
];

function compareDatesDescending(a, b) {
    const dateA = a.clmFirstReceivedDt.split('/').reverse().join('/');
    const dateB = b.clmFirstReceivedDt.split('/').reverse().join('/');
    if (dateA < dateB) {
        return 1;
    } else if (dateA > dateB) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

array.sort(compareDatesDescending);
console.log(array);

hope this helps :)

You can change the if to just return dateB - dateA

Point to noted: Javascript only accept dates format YYYY-MM-DD or MM-DD-YYYY. You must specify format first which format you are using, if you are using other than above two you should update your format first in your logic than sort the array. Like this
function sortDatesArr(arr,format){
  if(format === "DD-MM-YYY"){
      arr.map(item =>{
          let itm = item.split('/')
          let tempval1 = itm.pop()
          let tempval2 = itm.shift()
          itm.push(tempval2)
          itm.unshift(tempval1)
          return itm.join('/')
      }).sort((a, b) => {
        const dateA = new Date(a.clmFirstReceivedDt).getTime();
        const dateB = new Date(b.clmFirstReceivedDt).getTime();
        return dateB - dateA;
      });
  }else{
      arr.sort((a, b) => {
        const dateA = new Date(a.clmFirstReceivedDt).getTime();
        const dateB = new Date(b.clmFirstReceivedDt).getTime();
        return dateB - dateA;
      });
  }
  return arr
}
print(sortDatesArr(array,'DD-MM-YYY'))


You don't need to convert or parse dates, just compare them char by char:


let array = [
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "16/03/2023"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "17/03/2022"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "13/04/2024"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "06/03/2024"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "06/02/2024"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "12/03/2024"}
];

const idxs = [6,7,8,9,3,4,0,1];

array.sort((a, b) => {
  for(const i of idxs){
    const x = b.clmFirstReceivedDt[i], y = a.clmFirstReceivedDt[i];
    if(x > y) return 1;
    if(x < y) return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});

console.log(array);



And a benchmark
` Chrome/123
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                      n=6        |       n=60        |      n=600       |      n=6000     
Alexander       ■ 1.00x   x1m 285 | ■ 1.00x x100k 637 | ■ 1.00x x10k 850 | ■ 1.00x x100  96
trincot           1.73x   x1m 493 |   1.85x  x10k 118 |   1.60x  x1k 136 |   1.77x x100 170
Wimanicesir       7.61x x100k 217 |   7.63x  x10k 486 |   7.56x  x1k 643 |   6.66x x100 639
trincot regex    21.72x x100k 619 |  22.14x   x1k 141 |  22.47x x100 191 |  20.42x  x10 196
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `



const $chunk = [
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "16/03/2023"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "17/03/2022"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "13/04/2024"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "06/03/2024"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "06/02/2024"},
  {clmFirstReceivedDt: "12/03/2024"}
];

let $input = [];
$clone = arr => arr.slice();

// @benchmark trincot
$input.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.clmFirstReceivedDt.slice(6).localeCompare(a.clmFirstReceivedDt.slice(6)) ||
           b.clmFirstReceivedDt.slice(3).localeCompare(a.clmFirstReceivedDt.slice(3)) ||
           b.clmFirstReceivedDt.localeCompare(a.clmFirstReceivedDt)
});

// @benchmark trincot regex
$input.sort((a, b) => {
    // Extract the numeric parts and rejoin them in the propper order
    const dateA = a.clmFirstReceivedDt.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(.*)/, "$3$2$1");
    const dateB = b.clmFirstReceivedDt.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(.*)/, "$3$2$1");
    return dateB - dateA; // for descending order
});

// @benchmark Wimanicesir
function compareDatesDescending(a, b) {
    const dateA = a.clmFirstReceivedDt.split('/').reverse().join('/');
    const dateB = b.clmFirstReceivedDt.split('/').reverse().join('/');
    if (dateA < dateB) {
        return 1;
    } else if (dateA > dateB) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

$input.sort(compareDatesDescending);

// @benchmark Alexander
const idxs = [6,7,8,9,3,4,0,1];

$input.sort((a, b) => {
  for(const i of idxs){
    const x = b.clmFirstReceivedDt[i], y = a.clmFirstReceivedDt[i];
    if(x > y) return 1;
    if(x < y) return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));



